# Send command to an already opened .bat window from HTA/VBScript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, command, hta

I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to HTA or any real coding for that matter.
I can handle Excel VBA quite well so understand VBScript okish.

I currently have a Program that is run through a .bat file (I did not build this program nor know how it was written :))
I currently Launch the .bat file then if I want the program to do anything I parse a written command in the window.

I am trying to build an HTA to be able to do this for me. I have been able to write a script to launch the .bat file, but I can't get it to send a command to the already opened cmd/bat window.
I have searched for days & the only solutions to send a command are to call open the .bat file again, which doesn't work for me as I need it to be in the current opened window where the program is running.

This is what I have so far:

```
<head>
<title>HTA Test</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
     APPLICATIONNAME="HTA Test"
     SCROLL="yes"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">
Sub Launch

Dim objShell :Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
objShell.Run "cmd.exe /k Program_X.bat"
Set objShell=Nothing

End Sub

Sub Sendxxx
*******CODE NEEDED HERE TO SEND COMMAND "xxx" & enter TO Prgram_X**************
End Sub
</script>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Launch" name="launch"  onClick="Launch"><p> 

<input type="button" value="Sendxxx" name="Sendxxx"  onClick="Sendxxx"><p> 

</body>
```

If it is possible to also have in the body of the HTA, the last line displayed in the .bat window that would be a bonus!

Comment: Any chance replacing your current `objShell.Run` line with `objShell.Run "cmd /c echo xxx | Program_X.bat"` would solve your problem? As long as nothing in your .bat script before the "send command xxx" prompt consumes stdin, I think it should work and result in one fewer step for the user. Otherwise, I think you might need to use [Exec](https://ss64.com/vb/exec.html) instead of Run to get the PID of your `cmd` process, then `AppActivate PID` and `SendKeys`.  Or you could set a title in .bat and `AppActivate "title"` then `SendKeys`.

Comment: Hi Rojo, thanks for coming back to me.  unfortunately the first option won't work as th e.bat file needs to run & load first.  Also I want to be able to send commands to it intermittently throughout the day.  I'v looked into your other suggestions - I can't seem to get the PID of the bat files that running.  If I use Exec at first then it won't load & run the program. How do I set a title in the bat?

Comment: I commented on your answer below about the `title` command. `Exec` doesn't launch a window, but it does give you access to the command's output using `objName.StdOut.ReadLine()` and similar, which you could display within your HTA using `textareaElement.value` or `divElement.innerText`, etc.  `title` is probably the easiest solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I have it - it's a simple solution actually, thanks for the suggestions Rojo.  When I run the bat file, the window is named Administrator: =
so I just did:

```
Sub Sendxxx

Dim objShell: Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.AppActivate ("Administrator: =")
objShell.SendKeys ("xxx") & vbCr

End Sub
```

& that seemed to have worked

EDIT:
It doesn't actually work because when I run the .bat file onanother computer even though it has the cmd window up & running, it has no name & can't be found in the task manager, so I can't activate it.  Anyone with any ideas? I have asked this specific question here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780640/bat-cmd-window-doesnt-show-up-in-task-manager-has-no-name][1]

Comment: Within the .bat script, use the `title` command.  [More info](https://ss64.com/nt/title.html).